# How remove element from myType[]?

Tags: java

I've got a probleme on my code. I have to use a custom type array ( Colis[] ) and I made my own method to remove element from it :

```
public Colis[] casiers = new Colis[MAXVALUE];
...
public void removeColis(short num, int mode) {
    switch (mode) {
        case NUMCASIER:
            casiers[num]=null;
            break;
        case NUMCOLIS:
            for (int i=0; i<casiers.length; i++) {
                if (casiers[i].noColis==num){
                    casiers[i]=null;
                }
            }
        default :
            break;
    }
}
```

Seems like I don't do the good thing when I do `casiers[index]=null;`
because I catch a java.lang.NullPointerException.

My question is how should I remove the element contained in casiers[index] ?

Thks

Comment: Are you sure it's not `casiers[i].noColis` that is throwing the exception?

Comment: Could you show a full stack trace, just edit your question and put it in. That way we can see exactly where the issue is.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the length of casiers in your switch statement, looking at the value of num, and seeing if it is a valid index for that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With setting `casier`s entries to null it is prudent to use

```
  for (int i=0; i<casiers.length; i++) {
      if( casiers[i] == null ) continue;
      if (casiers[i].noColis==num){
            casiers[i]=null;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, you try to access casiers[i] without checking if anything actually exists.

```
        for (int i=0; i<casiers.length; i++) {
            if (casiers[i].noColis==num){
                casiers[i]=null;
            }
        }
```

Add a check to see if casiers[i] is not null

```
       for (int i=0; i<casiers.length; i++) {
            if(casiers[i] != null && casiers[i].noColis != null){
                if (casiers[i].noColis==num){
                    casiers[i]=null;
                }
            }
        }
```

This will make sure that casiers[i] is not null, and casiers[i].noColis is not null, before you try to access them in your code.